# Searching tmx lib can export/save map

Tags: python, python-3.x, tmx

I search a lib who can export/save `map` in tmx format with python3. I found:

[**PyTMX**](https://github.com/bitcraft/PyTMX/) but, [doc says](https://github.com/bitcraft/PyTMX/blob/e725814f57fd0f895fca5302639f80f7a32caa6f/docs/index.rst):

> Finally, there is no save feature. Once the map is loaded, it will be up to you to provide a way to save changes to the map. I've used the pickle module with good results.

[**tmxlib**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tmxlib/0.2.1) where [doc says](http://pytmxlib.readthedocs.org/en/v0.2.1/overview.html#loading-and-saving):

```
Saving is equally easy:

>>> map.save('saved.tmx')
>>> map_as_string = map.dump()
```

But pip installation fail (python3):

```
pip install tmxlib
Downloading/unpacking tmxlib
  Downloading tmxlib-0.2.1.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/home/bux/.virtualenvs/testsynergine2/build/tmxlib/setup.py) egg_info for package tmxlib

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/home/bux/.virtualenvs/testsynergine2/build/tmxlib/setup.py", line 59, in <module>
        import tmxlib
      File "/home/bux/.virtualenvs/testsynergine2/build/tmxlib/tmxlib/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
        from tmxlib.map import Map
      File "/home/bux/.virtualenvs/testsynergine2/build/tmxlib/tmxlib/map.py", line 5, in <module>
        from tmxlib import helpers, fileio, tileset, layer
      File "/home/bux/.virtualenvs/testsynergine2/build/tmxlib/tmxlib/tileset.py", line 8, in <module>
        from tmxlib import helpers, fileio, tile, image, terrain
      File "/home/bux/.virtualenvs/testsynergine2/build/tmxlib/tmxlib/image.py", line 28, in <module>
        preferred_image_class = image_classes[0]
    IndexError: list index out of range
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info

creating pip-egg-info/tmxlib.egg-info

writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/tmxlib.egg-info/top_level.txt

writing requirements to pip-egg-info/tmxlib.egg-info/requires.txt

writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/tmxlib.egg-info/dependency_links.txt

writing pip-egg-info/tmxlib.egg-info/PKG-INFO

writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/tmxlib.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found



reading manifest file 'pip-egg-info/tmxlib.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/tmxlib.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/home/bux/.virtualenvs/testsynergine2/build/tmxlib/setup.py", line 59, in <module>

    import tmxlib

  File "/home/bux/.virtualenvs/testsynergine2/build/tmxlib/tmxlib/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>

    from tmxlib.map import Map

  File "/home/bux/.virtualenvs/testsynergine2/build/tmxlib/tmxlib/map.py", line 5, in <module>

    from tmxlib import helpers, fileio, tileset, layer

  File "/home/bux/.virtualenvs/testsynergine2/build/tmxlib/tmxlib/tileset.py", line 8, in <module>

    from tmxlib import helpers, fileio, tile, image, terrain

  File "/home/bux/.virtualenvs/testsynergine2/build/tmxlib/tmxlib/image.py", line 28, in <module>

    preferred_image_class = image_classes[0]

IndexError: list index out of range

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
```

Do you know tmx libraries can do that, or a way to install tmxlib ?

Comment: `IndexError: list index out of range` Sounds like a problem in the library itself. I would recommend filing an issue in the library's bug tracker.

Comment: Good idea. But i don't found athor email or tracker for this project. Do you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed the same library right now with python3 successfully using pip. If pip install is not working for you then:

1. Download the zip package from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tmxlib/0.2.1
2. Extract the above package.
3. In the extracted directory there is a script "setup.py"
4. Run this script via terminal by giving command

   python setup.py install

It will work hopefully. Also I think the library is fine..may be there is a bug in your version of pip instead.

Answer (score 0):

Available other tmx lib: http://pythonhosted.org/tmx/ (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tmx . This can load and save.